# Excel VBA extended toolset

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I start a new excel VBA project, I always need to create myself some new functionality such as these Boolean functions to check if things exist, are empty, etc:

```
 fncSheetExists(ByVal sheetname) as Boolean
 fncArrayEmpty(ByRef array) as Boolean
 fncItemInArray(ByVal item, ByRef array) as Boolean
```

It adds a hundred or so lines to each new project. Is there a kind of toolset library which exists and comes with ms Office which already does these things? I feel I'm writing redundant code.

Cheers for the help in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just make your new project open a workbook with these functions in as a hidden book? This type of thing could be used in PERSONAL.xlsb but I had so many problems with it that I just created my own workbook with classes of my own functions in. Each project I create refers to this workbook.

Comment: There are no built-in functions or single-line methods for those three tasks, however if you're using 100 lines to do them, I bet your code could be compressed considerably (if you were to post it)

Comment: @jamheadart - i assume you mean "hidden worksheet"?  Interesing to hear your feedback on `personal.xlb`. An alternative is to create a workbook with your custom functions, and save it as a `.xlam` **add-in**, and then add the add-in to Excel and then the functions will be available to all workbooks... (Disclaimer: I couldn't get this working myself - although I gave up pretty fast. I think my issue was that there's possibly a difference between worksheet add-ins and VBA add-ins..?)

Comment: No I mean a workbook you can open in a hidden window. Much like the default PERSONAL.xlsb that would be created when recording macros. I had quite a few issues with this back on 2010/2013 and particularly when opening Excel via .Net applications with the Excel.Interops functions.

Comment: @jamheadart the scripts are often distributed elsewhere - a personal or add-on workbook wouldn't really work. I'm looking specifically for a library which does this.

Comment: @ashleedawg thanks, but it was just an estimate and those were an example few. They usually only take about 2 to 10 lines each incl. Error handling.

Comment: It might be easier to answer this if we understood what you are doing. How could there be a library to do all of the little checks you want to do like "Other random handy functions that I like to use.dll"?

Comment: Totally beside the point, but really you could do all of these including function definitions in about 11 lines of code. For instance: `fncArrayEmpty = Len(Join(arr, "")) = 0` or `fncItemInArray = InStr(1, "|" & Join(arr, "|") & "|", "|" & item & "|") > 0` and the `fncSheetExists` can be done in about three lines.

Comment: I got that `fncSheetExists` down to one line (cheating though): `On Error Resume Next: fncSheetExists = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Name = sheetname` Totally going to use that in some future vba monstrosity.

Comment: A couple of other options here: [Roll your own dll](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html) which would be pretty simple and you can use the excel interop library in C# to work with the Excel application (just like VBA really). You could also just export your module or class and reimport it into each project. I do this with some database classes I wrote for ADODB. It pulls hundreds of lines of code in, but so what? It's in it's own class module and works 100% and all I have to do is import the thing each time I need it.

Comment: @JNevill I like this suggestion - cheers. That's a definite thing I'll tinker with.

On the writing things in one line issue: that's not the important bit, it's just that I have to write it for each project that's the issue :)
Was hoping there was a standard 'vba tools' library I was just totally missing

Comment: I think the real trick here is that you probably distribute these workbooks to other folks. If the code is hiding in a seperate workbook (hidden, personal, etc) then it won't be available for the other computers. The same is true with rolling your own DLL and using Tools>>References. However if you have a shared drive then maybe you could skirt around that (of course then you hit the "Trusted locations" issue and walking a user through that is about the most painful experience in the world...) caveats everywhere you turn. Anyway, export/import module is probably the way I would go. No Fuss.

Comment: 1. `Personal.xlsb` is made specifically for this purpose when operating only on your own computer.
2. In case you need to share this across multiple colleagues or whatever, saving as `xlam` and providing them the add-in would be the best option.
3. To answer the question "Is there a kind of toolset library which exists and comes with ms Office which already does these things" - No, but this is the premise for option 2 (`xlam` / add-in)

DLL is an option, like writing add-in using interop in C#/vb.net. The sharing issue will remain. Basically - someone add an answer please :)